# toString() doesn't return string value on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to return a string every time something is typed in the input field. In other words, with every keystroke, I want to see in the console it being typed out. So typing out stack in the input, I want to see:

```
s
st
sta
stac
stack
```

My initial code was:

```js
$("#input").on('input', function() {
    var userInput = $(this).text();
    console.log(userInput);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="type">
```

Which was returning blank. Ok, let's try `toString()`:

```js
$("#input").on('input', function() {
    var userInput = $(this).text();
    console.log(userInput.toString());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="type">
```

Same result. Why? Doesn't `toString()` convert a data type to string and shouldn't it be logged in console.

Why in the first example without `toString()` does it not return the text value?

http://api.jquery.com/text/ - it says

> The result of the .text() method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements.

What am I missing? What's going on here?

**EDIT:** silly mistake, I needed `.val();` but that leads me to another question:

Howcome the console was blank if `.text()` returns a string?

Comment: An input store the value in `this.value` or `$(this).val()`, not as text

Comment: `<span>This is the kind of text</span>` that `jQuery.text()` returns. The value of a input field is not stored in the html markup of that node.

Comment: *"Howcome the console was blank if .text() returns a string?"* an empty string is also a string. And if the string doesn't contain any chars *(or if the whole row contains only whitespace)*, what do you expect the console to show?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method to get the value of input is `.val()` and not `.text()`. See the application below:

```js
$("#input").on('input', function() {
  var userInput = $(this).val();
  console.log(userInput);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="type">
```

You essentially do not need `.toString()` as `.val()` give the string value only.

Comment: ok but if `.text()` returns a string, why did it console log blank?

Comment: @kawnah no, `.text()` return the inner text of the HTML element like `div`, `span`... instead input have `.value` property and jQuery has a method `.val()` to fetch it. In short `.text()` does not work on `input` element to fetch its value.

Answer (score 3):

You're so close! .text() is for `innerText` type stuff. What you're looking for `.val()` this harvest the value from the input.

```js
$("#input").on('input', function() {
    var userInput = $(this).val();
    console.log(userInput.toString());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="type">
```

Comment: You're so close, too. `.text()` is for [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) type stuff. For innerHTML stuff there's [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: Howcome the console was blank if .text() returns a string?

Comment: @Thomas Ah! I innerHTML'd when I should have innerText'd, I corrected my answer.

Comment: @kawnah I all elements have a text attribute, inputs are empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `val()` function instead.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```js
$("#input").on('input', function() {
    var userInput = $(this).val();
    console.log( userInput);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="type">
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is echo the value, the jQuery object is unnecessary.  You can just use the `this.value`.

```js
$("#input").on('input', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="type">
```